# Algebraic system of equations problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the follow system of equations:

$$x+y+z=5$$
$$\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{xz}=5$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=53$$

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two equations give $xyz=1$. From the last equation we get $$x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y+z)^3+3xyz-3(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)$$ and hence $xy+yz+zx=5$, so $x,y,z$ are the roots of the cubic $a^3-5a^2+5a-1=0$.

That factorises as $(a-1)(a^2-4a+1)=0$, so the roots are $1,2\pm\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=5-x-y$. By computing the [$S$-polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger's_algorithm), the last two equations yield either
$$
x-1=0, \; y^2 - 4y + 1=0,
$$
or
$$
x^2 - 4x + 1=0, \; x+y - 4=0,
$$
or 
$$
x^2 - 4x + 1=0, \; y - 1=0.
$$
Here the quadratic equation $z^2-4z+1=0$ has the two solutions $2\pm \sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

*HINT*: Find $xy + yz + zx$ and $xyz$. Then use the three given equations to find $x$, $y$ and $z$ by considering the corresponding the roots of the polynomial $t^3 + \alpha t^2 + \beta t + \gamma$ where $-\alpha = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$, $\beta = x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_1$ and $\gamma = -x_1x_2x_3$